# What is reference counter with respect to Device Driver Model?

Tags: linux-device-driver, device-driver, reference-counting

While studying **Understanding The Linux Kernel** I came across **reference counter** in `Kobject` structure and **container**.
So, how does it helps to map these structures?
Given below is a pragraph from ULK 3rd edition.

> The kref field is a structure of type `k_ref` consisting of a single refcount field. As the name implies, this field is the reference counter for the kobject, but it may act also as the reference counter for the container of the kobject. The `kobject_get( )` and `kobject_put( )` functions increase and decrease, respectively, the reference counter; if the counter reaches the value zero, the resources used by the kobject are released and the release method of the `kobj_type` object of the `kobject` is executed. This method, which is usually defined only if the container of the kobject was allocated dynamically, frees the container itself.

Similarly in some more context this reference counter was used.
I want to know the practical mapping of the reference counter.

Comment: Have you read [kref documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kref.txt)? It looks nice for introducing into reference count used in the kernel.

Comment: Thanks, i am new to linux, i am just  going through it.

Answer (score 0):

key functions of a "kobject" is to serve as a reference counter for the object
in which it is embedded. As long as references to the object exist,the object (and the code that supports it) must continue to exist. low-level functions for manipulating a kobject’s reference counts are:

```
struct kobject *kobject_get(struct kobject *kobj);
void kobject_put(struct kobject *kobj);
```

Calling to kobject_get increments kobject's reference Counter and Returns a pointer to the kobject and if kobject is in the process of getting destroyed, this particular Operation Fails and kobject_get Returns "Null".

Similarly when the reference is to be released, the call to kobject_put decrements the reference Counter and frees the object.

Reference counting for struct dev can be implemented as follows:

```
struct kobject *dev_get(struct dev *p)
{
struct module *owner = p->owner;
struct kobject *kobj;

if (owner && !try_module_get(owner))
return NULL;
kobj = kobject_get(&p->kobj);
if (!kobj)
module_put(owner);
return kobj;
}
```

I hope this answer may help you in certain way to understand something about kobject and reference Counter :-)

Comment: I have read this in the book I mentioned , the problem was that I  doubt that it is something more than incrementing and decrementing.

Comment: I think without explicit ref counting, the kernel cannot easily tell if the device is still being used (because many drivers can be using the same device or object). So this is for management of resources like memory?